# Problem when swapping python list entries

Tags: python, list, typeerror, swap

I have tried to do this:

```
A = [["test1"],["test2"]]
A[0][0], A[1][0] = A[1][0], A[0][0]
```

When executing `print(A)` the output is as expected: The two entries are swapped.

With this code however "TypeError: "str" object does not support item assignment" (line 8) is being raised:

```
import sys

try:
  with open ("Values", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
      for j in range(len(lines[i])//2):  
        lines[i][j], lines[i][len(lines[i])-1-j] = lines[i][len(lines[i])-1-j], lines[i][j]

except FileNotFoundError:
  print("File could not be found.")
```

Comment: Wait so from A = [["test1"],["test2"]]  you want A = [["test2"],["test1"]]?

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your posted program dies on a missing file.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your file read with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?  Remember to include the full error message.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak Don't change variable names in the OP. I rolled back your edit.

Comment: @wjandrea Sorry. Just translated "Zeilen" from German to English. But thanks for the comment.

Comment: Running the first snippet, I get `IndexError: list index out of range`. It seems like `A[0][1]` was supposed to be `A[1][0]`. Next, what are you confused about specifically? It looks like somewhere you have a string where you were expecting a list. For help with debugging, please provide a [mre] including input, expected output, and actual output, i.e. error, including the full traceback.

Comment: @wjandrea yep you are right. I will edit it.

Comment: @wjandrea I think if you would run the first snippet now, it would work. I think line 8 of the second code is principally the same, yet it does not work as I receive a TypeError. That I find confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially already answered your question. "python strings are not mutable" while lists are.

See you can do

```py
l = ['a','b','c']
l[0] = x
# ['x','b','c']
```

while you can't do

```py
l = 'abc'
l[0] = x
# TypeError: "str" object does not support item assignment
```

And your line `lines[i][j]` tries to change one character in a string.

Instead try converting the string to a list first. Then swapping the characters. Then converting it back to a string:

```
temp = list(lines[i])
temp[j], temp[len(lines[i])-1-j] = temp[len(lines[i])-1-j], temp[j]
lines[i] = "".join(temp)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I now see why the first code worked: I swapped Arrays, which is possible while in the second code I was trying to swap characters of a string which does not work because strings are immutable.

Comment: "array" isn't the correct term in Python: in your first example `A` is a `list`.